# How to jump Trie Node in Trie data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, trie

I'm trying to use a Trie to solve the following problem. Let's consider these strings to be inserted in a Trie:

```
String s1 = "Elephant";
String s2 = "Alfphant";
String s3 = "Ilophnit";
```

I would like to know if there is at least one string containing the characters: '**l**' in the second position, '**h**' in the fifth position and '**n**' in the sixth position.

I'm using a simple [Trie implementation](https://www.baeldung.com/trie-java), and my goal is to get efficient research using Trie. This is the proposed function:

```
    boolean containsNode(String word) {
        TrieNode current = root;
        TrieNode node = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char ch = word.charAt(i);

            node = current.getChildren().get(ch);
            if (node == null) {
                return false;
            }
            current = node;
        }
        return current.isEndOfWord();
    }
```

Assuming that I know the characters to find and their positions, I thought about creating a jump in the iterations. However, in this way, the complexity of the search increases because I should consider all the children of each node.

Do you have any solutions for me? Are there other types of Trie, Tree, or data structures that can efficiently solve my problem?

Comment: Are you obliged to use a data structure like Trie to solve this problem ?

Comment: No, but I can have a large number of strings, and I would like to perform a fast search.

Comment: Ok,  then Trie is the best option especially if you need a dynamic structure adding and remove nodes in it.

Comment: Ok, but do you have any solutions for my problem?

Comment: You have to modify your function passing as additional parameters one counter and one `Map<Integer, Char>`  for comparing chars while the return will be an or of the children and the root.

Comment: I had already thought about the parameters, the problem is that I don't know how to change the function.